# Why is this CSS broken in certain web IDEs or browsers?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this code that is supposed to look like this.
[image]

BUT, this is broken on services like [Codepen](https://codepen.io/leochoo/pen/vYZKPJO), JSFiddle, [Liveweave](https://liveweave.com/Z7tBLj) etc.
**EVEN on Stackoverflow!!!** They are all broken here.

However, it is working fine on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@leonardchoo/GoldenCleanDecimals#index.html) or when I run it locally.

I see only Liveweave raising an errorlike `expected rbrace at line` ..
but I did not run into this trouble when running other examples. Why would this be the case?

I linked the code to above services but here is the code

(S)CSS Masterclass

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.grid {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.grid:first-child {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid:last-child {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>(S)CSS Masterclass</title>
</head>

<body>
  auto-fill
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  auto-fit
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The HTML you add in most of the editors is placed in the body. And most of the editors also add additional things to the `body`. And due to how error correction in browsers works, those will remove the `body`, `head` and `html` elements you provided, as those are not valid in the body, and places their children in the actual `body` element. And that results in your `.grid` elements not being the first/last child.

Comment: No problem on Stackblitz, demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-bnnqhf?file=index.html